# How to convert my Xml File into customized Xml file using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I want to Convert my Input Xml File into more customized xml file by using XSLT 2.0.

This is my Input Xml File...

```
<w:document>

    <w:body>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph1</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph2</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Heading1”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>First Heading1 Paragraph</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph3</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph4</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Heading2”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>First Heading2 Paragraph</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph5</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Heading3”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>First Heading3 Paragraph</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph6</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

          <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Heading3”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Second Heading3 Paragraph</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph7</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>


             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Heading1”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Second Heading1 Paragraph</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>
             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph8</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

             <w:p>
                  <w:pPr pStyle=”Normal”/>                

                  <w:r>
                      <w:t>Normal Paragraph9</w:t>
                  </w:r>
              </w:p>

    </w:body>

</w:document>
```

And I Expected Output XML File is Given Below...

```
<Document>
<Paragraph>Normal Paragraph1</Paragraph>
<Paragraph>Normal Paragraph2</Paragraph>
<Heading1>
       <Title>First Heading1 Paragraph</Title>
       <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph3</Paragraph>
       <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph4</Paragraph>
       <Heading2>
           <Title>First Heading2 Paragraph</Title>
           <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph5</Paragraph>
           <Heading3>
              <Title>First Heading3 Paragraph</Title>
              <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph6</Paragraph>
           </Heading3>
           <Heading3>
              <Title>Second Heading3 Paragraph</Title>
              <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph7</Paragraph>
           </Heading3>
       </Heading2>
 </Heading1>
 <Heading1>
       <Title>Second Heading1 Paragraph</Title>
       <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph8</Paragraph>
       <Paragraph>Normal Paragraph9</Paragraph>
</Heading1>
</Document>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the whole thing for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible. A XSLT manual is available under http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.